# Combine two Python lists with partly empty sublists

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a nested list (list of lists) where each sublist might contain one or more elements (integers) but some are even empty:

```
mynestedlist = [[], [], [], [4,10], [4], [10]]
```

In addition I have another list of the same length (all integers):

```
otherlist = [2,4,14,32,21,12]
```

Now I'd like to get a combined list of tuples for elements where my nested list element is not empty. Actually each tuple should contain elements from both lists.

For example the first non-empty list in  `mynestedlist` is the 4th wich is `[4,10]`. The corresponding element from otherlist is 32. This information should be coersed to two tuples `(32,4)` and `(32,10)`. So if there are more than one entry in the sublist of `mynestedlist` than multiple tuples should be created. 
Finally the output should be `[(32,4),(32,10),(21,4),(12,10)]`. How can this be done in an efficient way?

So what I tried so far is

*) to check if a sublist is empty using the sum of the sublist

```
[sum(x)>0 for x in mynestedlist]
```

*) to combine both lists into a dictionary

```
combined_list = dict(zip(otherlist,mynestedlist))
```

I am not sure at all if this is the way to go?

Comment: Are you planning to do something on your own? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34182181/filter-python-list-of-lists-by-another-list

Comment: stackoverflow is not a code writing service. Please give examples of what you've tried and what isn't working and someone will try to help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is actually pretty straightforward with a list comprehension,

```
>>> [(b, e) for a, b in zip(mynestedlist, otherlist) for e in a]
[(32, 4), (32, 10), (21, 4), (12, 10)]
```

You can use [`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) if on Python 2.x and have long lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with two simple loops. I'm pretty sure this is as efficient as it could get.

```
result = [] 
A = [2,4,14,32,21,12]
B = [[], [], [], [4,10], [4], [10]]
for i in range(len(A)):
    for x in B[i]:
        result.append((A[i],x))
print result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[(otherlist[i], vv) for i, v in enumerate(mynestedlist) for vv in v]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
out = []
for a, b in zip(mynestedlist, otherlist):
     for ele in a:
        out.append((b, ele))
print(out)
```